# Get a friendly name for browser/computer

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to retrieve the computer name when developing a Chrome Extension, for example "Jenny-PC"?

At first glance I did not find the API, but maybe I missed something.

Comment: This could be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354496/create-a-chrome-plugin-to-get-computer-information

Comment: Ah... I see now that Chrome allows for NPAPI plugins. This is too heavy a gun for my purposes. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you are quite the daredevil, you could try to extract that info from a NPAPI plugin. This is quite dangerous, as you can read more about [on the chrome extension site](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html)

Answer (score 0):

No directly, for security reasons extensions can't access OS services.

But, hacker way, you may find some odd way to get what you're looking for.

If your extension has file:// permission, it can read system configuration files.

If you can get the user drop some file containing the name you want on some receiver in your extension's page, you can read it with HTML5 FileReader object.

If you can get the user download and execute some script you wrote (for example a .bat in Windows), it can grab that name and send to the extensions in various ways:
- writing it in a file the extension can read
- executing something like

```
"c:\chrome install folder\chrome.exe" chrome://extensions/yourextensionkey/receiver.html?name=thenameyourellokingfor
```

About file:// permission
Chrome Web Store doesn't allow uploading nor publishing extensions with such permission.  But the extension works if you install it as a developer, or as .crx .
I'm not sure, but I think you can upload it to Chrome web store modifying it, in order to ask for permission.